# Installing Pylab/Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a program that plots a graph, which made me look into
Matplotlib.

I found a tutorial that started out with this little program, that worked fine:

```
from pylab import *

def main():
    X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 256, endpoint=True)
    C,S = np.cos(X), np.sin(X)
    plot(X,C)
    plot(X,S)
    show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then I tried to run it on another computer, where it did not work at all. I tried to download Pylab and Matplotlib. When I had installed Matplotlib it demanded something called dateutil, when I got dateutil it demanded something called six. I downloaded six, but it didn't work properly.

It doesn't feel like I'm on the right track. What should I do to get a proper installation?

EDIT:

I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Python\mscript\listdb2.py", line 19, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 226, in <module>
    import matplotlib.finance
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\finance.py", line 21, in <module>
    from matplotlib.dates import date2num
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\dates.py", line 119, in <module>
    from dateutil.rrule import (rrule, MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU, YEARLY,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dateutil\rrule.py", line 18, in <module>
    from six import advance_iterator, integer_types
ImportError: No module named six
```

The file six.py is located in C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\six\six.py

The six directory also contains a file called test_six.py. If I try to run this program I also get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_six.py", line 5, in <module>
    import.py
ImportError: No module named py
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Also what error are you getting?

Answer (score 15):

If Anaconda installed and it is already in your environment path, you can get it simply using

```
conda install matplotlib
```

in command line and then call in Python with

```
from pylab import *
```

This work for me fine as "pip install" and "easy_install" both on Win and Linux caused a lot of issues

Answer (score 7):

Installing packages on *nix is easy using [pip](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Pip allows you to easily install packages from [the Python Package Index (PyPI)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi) with a simple `pip install matplotlib`. This should install all dependencies, but if it does not then you can install them manually (for instance `pip install python-dateutil`).

Using pip with Windows is possible though slightly more difficult for packages that require compilers and such. However, installing Python programs on Windows is simple if you use these [Windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) provided by Christoph Gohlke.

The particular ones for matplotlib can be found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#matplotlib). Note that you can also find similar binaries for `python-dateutil`, `six`, etc if necessary.

*As an aside: I would strongly suggest you look into using the full `matplotlib.pyplot` API rather than `pylab`. It's much more powerful and useful, but this is just some aside advice :) *

Comment: This works, see more detailed intructions below:
run "cmd" in admin mode
cd "c:\Program Files\Python35\Scripts\"
pip install matplotlib